# .htaccess directory routing

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been banging my head against my keyboard with this one, and I'm sure it's something stupidly simple that I'm missing, but...

I'm using tinyMVC, which normally routes requests with /index.php/hello/foo or whatever. I'm trying to set up an .htaccess file so that I can do away with the /index.php/ and just request /hello/foo... the tinyMVC documentation suggests the following (files should be served from /web when accessing /):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/index.php/$1 [L]
```

However, it only returns a broken link. If I use a query string instead of a directory (i.e. index.php?qs=$1), it serves the file (with query string attached) just fine, but that method doesn't work with tinyMVC routing.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: my file structure looks like this:

```
docroot/
       /web/
           /index.php
       /.htaccess
```

Ideally, requests to mysite.com/hello would be transparently routed to mysite.com/web/index.php/hello, which the MVC controller would recognize.

Comment: also what is the '/web/' directory for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess a missing '/' at the start of the target

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

*EDIT*

Ok your comment did help the rewrite rule expects URL not directories so you shouldn't write the web part.

Comment: web or /web, no deal. The /web directory holds all the publicly-accessible resources (I had it set as the web directory, but I changed it back to / in case that was the problem. It wasn't).

Answer (score 1):

Check the error log

```
/var/log/httpd/error_log
```

while you get the broken page.

It may be due to lack of permission to .htaccess file.

The .htaccess file has to be in the document root folder.

```
DOCROOT/
       /web/
           /index.php
       /.htaccess
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: .htaccess is in doc root. I'll edit the question to be more clear on the file structure.